# componentDidUpade update child arrays and merge

Tags: reactjs

I have an issue with my react components. I have parent where I have API calls to return data from db, then I pass two arrays of results to child.

```
   <Child items1={this.state.items1} items2={this.state.items2} />
```

In child I have to merge these two arrays by same ID's, and = to state.

```
  public componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
   //Have to check if these props are updated here
        const mergeArray = (source, merge, by) => source.map(item => ({
          ...item,
          ...(merge.find(i => i[by] === item[by]) || {}),
        }));
        this.setState({
          itemsMerged: mergeArray(this.props.items1, this.props.items2,'Id')
        });
      }
```

I need to chceck for both props if they update so :

```
 public componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.items1 !== prevProps.items1) {
        console.log(this.props.items1);
      }

    if(this.props.items2 !== prevProps.items2) {
      console.log(this.props.items2);
    }
  }
```

How to nested these two conditions or figure it out in right way.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a

> merged = new Map('your element id',{your element})

and in each time componentDidUpdate you take the two arrays and update each element in the map with its id and then you can update state using the map in a proper way